# Print variables in speech marks

Tags: python

I'm asking the user for their physical attributes (what hair colour, eye colour, etc).

```
chooseCharacter = input("What character do you want to use? (%s or %s): " % (charOne, charTwo)) 
if chooseCharacter=="%s" % charOne:

attributes=[]

hair= input("what colour hair does %s have?" % (charOne))

build= input("what build is %s?" % (charOne))

eyes= input("what colour eyes does %s have?" % (charOne))

weaponOfChoice= input("what weapon is %s using?" % (charOne))

defence= input("what defence does %s use?" % (charOne))

("%s")=('hello %s. Am i right to say you have',hair,'right?. You should also be',build,'and have',eyes,'eyes.' % charOne)
```

How can I print out the description?

> hello (charOne) am i right to say you have (defined) hair, (defined)
>   eyes

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what error do you get ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the exact output you are currently getting when trying to run it

Comment: To print, you use `print`. Not that weird `("%s")=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got `("%s")=(...)` from. I've never seen anything like that before. Make sure you compare your code to known good code.

The last line should be:

```
print 'hello %s. Am i right to say you have %s right?. You should also be %s and have %s eyes.' % (charOne, hair, build, eyes)
```

Or split onto two lines:

```
print 'hello %s. Am i right to say you have %s right?' % (charOne, hair)
print 'You should also be %s and have %s eyes.' % (build, eyes)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure that indentation is correct after "if".
Then, the last line seems to be wrong.

This example will work:

```
charOne="a"
charTwo="b"

chooseCharacter = input("What character do you want to use? (%s or %s): " % (charOne, charTwo)) 
if chooseCharacter=="%s" % charOne:

    attributes = []

    hair= input("what colour hair does %s have?" % (charOne))

    build= input("what build is %s?" % (charOne))

    eyes= input("what colour eyes does %s have?" % (charOne))

    weaponOfChoice= input("what weapon is %s using?" % (charOne))

    defence= input("what defence does %s use?" % (charOne))

    s=('hello %s. Am i right to say you have %s right?. You should also be %s and have %s eyes.' % (charOne,hair, build,eyes))

    print(s)
```